# How to get "kategori" in view to the function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to get "kategori" from add-produk.php to my function in admin.php . But still not showing the result, any solution ?

here my code :

```
<select name="kategori" class="form-control">
                                        <?php foreach($allGroups as $key){ 
                          $categori = $key['category_code'];
                                          echo '<option value="<?= $categori">'.$key['name'].'</option>';
                                        }?>
                                    </select>
```

and this is my function from admin.php

```
$category_code = $this->input->post('kategori');
    echo "this is what i get : "$category_code;
```

Comment: One issue is that `echo "this is what i get : "$category_code;` is not valid, you need a `.` between those like `echo "this is what i get : ". $category_code;` or just put the var inside the double quotes like `echo "this is what i get : $category_code";`

Comment: If you still dont get the expected output, ensure that your form uses `method="POST"` and not  `method="GET"`

Comment: i've changed to this :
echo "this is what i get :".$category_code;
but still not showing the result, am i wrong at the add-produk or the function ?

Comment: Did you check  that your form uses `method="POST"` and not `method="GET"`?

Comment: <form action="<?= base_url('admin/proses_add_produk') ?>" method="POST">

this is my form action

Comment: What do you get if you run something like `var_dump($this->input->post())` ?

Comment: Oh wait, can you please try updating `value="<?= $categori">` to `value="<?= $categori>"` ? ie move the final `"` to be outside the php closing `>`

Comment: if i change value="<?= $categori>" my dropdown not showing sir

Comment: Sorry, do `value="<?= $categori ?>">`

Comment: oh ok, now the drop down updated. but still not solve my problem.
the <select name="kategori" class="form-control"> are not calling to the function.

Comment: If you right click on the select options in your html form and select "Inspect element", when you look at the html, does the `value` property have the expected value there?

Comment: its showing like this
<option value="<?= $categori ?>">Deking</option>

The deking here is from .$key['name'].

Comment: Oh, I missed the `echo` at the start of that line, do this:  `echo "<option value="$categori">{$key['name']}</option>";`

Comment: echo "<option value="$categori">{$key['name']}</option>";

its getting error sir.

Comment: Whoops, wrong quote type in the middle, do `echo "<option value='$categori'>{$key['name']}</option>";`

Comment: WOAAHHH ITS WORK SIRRR, BIG THANKSSSS <3

Comment: Awesome! YVW, glad to hear it :)